# Defining 2D array inside class of Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am new to Perl and I am trying to define a 2D array as an attribute of my class in Perl. I define my class as follows,

```
sub new{
my $class = shift;
my $self = {};

my @board = [];
for (my $i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
    for(my $j = 0; $j < 8; $j++){
        $board[$i][$j] = '.';
    }
}
$self->{board} = @board;
bless($self, $class);
return $self;
}
```

But later on when I try to access the board field like this

```
$self->{board}[$i][$j] = ' ';
```

I got an error saying

```
Can't use string ("8") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way of doing this? I do not want to just delete use strict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed your code to what I'm sure was your intention,
see the lines changed and comment # not

```
sub new{
my $class = shift;
my $self = {};

my @board = ();  # not []
for (my $i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
    for(my $j = 0; $j < 8; $j++){
        $board[$i][$j] = '.';
    }
}
$self->{board} = \@board; # not @board
bless($self, $class);
return $self;
}
```

or

```
sub new{
my $class = shift;
my $self = {};

my $board = []; # not @board
for (my $i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
    for(my $j = 0; $j < 8; $j++){
        $board->[$i][$j] = '.';
    }
}
$self->{board} = $board; # not @board
bless($self, $class);
return $self;
}
```

about your `my @board=[];` is the same as `=([],);` assign a list (that perl calls ARRAY) whose first element is a reference to an ARRAY to @board, but this is neither what make your code fail because you overwrite this empty array reference allocation and assignment to position zero.
The @board is a list not a reference to it as $self->{board} expect

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. This is a pretty good first answer! Make sure your formatting of inline code is consistent and maybe add a link to documentation. Keep up the good work! :)

Comment: I changed according to your code version #1, but I still got the same error when I try to access it in a subroutine.

Comment: Oh, I seem to find the problem, I try to use $self->{board}[$i][$j] directly in the subroutine, which is empty in subroutine. But don't subroutine have access to the attribute of their own class?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place a reference to array inside your `$self` hash. Right now you're placing a value of array in scalar context - which is its length `8`. Of course you can't later use this as a reference to anything.

```
$self->{board} = \@board;
```

Comment: But what if I don't want to change the value? Do I have to copy it every time I want to make some temporary changes?

Comment: What should be the correct way of accessing it in a subroutine?

Comment: @LouisKwong can you explain more on your first question? Re the second question, you should define accessors for a specific field, so you can go `$obj->tile( $x, $y )` where tile is a field in the board.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you explanations of what the problem is with your constructor. I'll add, that you can simplify it a bit by omitting the `$board` variable and using C-style loops.

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;

  my $self = {};
  $self->{board} = [];

  for my $i (1 .. 8) {
    for my $j (1 .. 8) {
      $self->{board}[$i][$j] = '.';
    }
  }

  return bless $self, $class;
}
```

I'd also add the following three methods which make it easier to set and get the elements of the board:

```
sub board {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->{board};
}

sub set_board_element {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($i, $j, $val) = @_;

  $self->board->[$i][$j] = $val;
}

sub get_board_element {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($i, $j) = @_;

  return $self->board->[$i][$j];
}
```

Have you considered using [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) to write your class? It will make your life easier. In particular, [Array traits](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array) seem like a good fit for your problem.